# In a Lightning Data Table in LWC, when I try to click on a hyperlink on Row2, it highlights Row1, but opens Row2 in the end

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-datatable

In a Lightning Data Table in LWC, when I try to click on a hyperlink on Row2, it highlights Row1 but opens Row2 in the end.

The Rows are actually a list of records which are from a custom object and upon clicking the hyperlink it will download the record from a different source system.

My question is, is this expected? Because I am unable to stop the highlighting after clicking on a row.

Attached image below for reference where I click row 2 and row 1 gets highlighted for a fraction of a second and then it highlights back row2 and eventually the action happens on row2. Want to know if this is expected behavior. If there is any documentation , happy to go through. Thanks.

[image]

Below is the Lightning Data Table Code which is generic. This is being called in a child component which passes the data to this data table dynamically. The keyfield is a salesforce record Id.

This keyfield comes from a metadata record from a custom metadatatype.

metadata goes like this:

```
{
"keyfield": "ID",
"hideCheckboxColumn": false,
"data": [
{
"ID": "Id",
"FileLeafRef": "abc",
"Name": "Name",
"xde": "def",
"sdf": "sdf",
"gre": "asd",
"wer": "brb",
"wes": "ffe",
"cds": "iyf",
"cda":"cws",
"bgw":"kia",
"CreatedDate": "CreatedDate",
"dea": "fea",
"wea": "gta",
"DocumentLink" : "documentLink"
}
],
"columns": [
{
"label": "File Name",
"fieldName": "FileLeafRef",
"type": "button",
"typeAttributes":{"label": { "fieldName": "FileLeafRef"},
"variant": "base",
"name": "Preview"
},
"cellAttributes": {"class": "slds-text-link"}
},
```

I have events which gets the information of the selected row(please note I am not using checkbox here, instead I am just clicking the hyperlink).

The event info shows the correct information of the row which I have clicked on the hyperlink. But somehow it highlights the other row.

```
  <lightning-datatable data-id="datarow" key-field={keyfield} hide-checkbox-column={hideCheckboxColumn}
                    suppress-bottom-bar show-row-number-column={showRowNumberColumn} column-widths-mode="auto"
                    row-number-offset=0 data={currentPageData} columns={columns} selected-rows={selection}
                    onrowselection={getSelectedRows} onrowaction={handleRowAction} sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                    sorted-by={sortedBy} onsort={handleSort}  max-row-selection="1">
                </lightning-datatable>
```

Comment: No, that would not be expected. Do you have any code to share?

Comment: @sfdcfox : Have added some code, let me know if that's fine to get some understanding.